# Null checking in binding expression

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, nullreferenceexception

Does WPF binding expression syntax have a null-checking mechanism? So for example My `TextBox` shows the `Address` field of the first element of an array of `People` objects, like this:

```
Text="{Binding AllPeople[0].Address}"
```

`AllPeople` can at times be null itself. This doesn't cause any exceptions, but WPF silently records an binding error message in the Immediate window. Is there a way to avoid this by specifying null-safety in the Path expression? Something on the lines of `AllPeople?[0].Address`.

Note: I know this can easily be done using Converters. I'm looking for a shorthand notation.

Comment: You can try defining some null (empty) instance of your class, use that instead of null. It's like the so-called [Null Object Pattern](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwjH0py4-7zIAhXi2qYKHZc9DLk&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FNull_Object_pattern&usg=AFQjCNGR73DVLM27yHD-6_HvvIX57jS6Hg&sig2=O2aC1cQyC4iXKfbltHscOA&bvm=bv.104819420,d.dGY). It may be some kind of overkill. The purpose of checking null  here may be to show some custom string when null, so I think using Converter is fairly standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your binding, you can configure two optional properties: [TargetNullValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) and [FallbackValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue(v=vs.110).aspx). The first one should be what you need.

The `FallbackValue` will be applied if the binding does not work at runtime.

Example:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EnabledFlagInViewModel, TargetNullValue=false}"
```

Comment: In the case of OP, the `AllPeople` is what possibly null. But the actual path is `AllPeople[0].Address`. So I believe that you need to change the Path to `AllPeople` before being able to use `TargetNullValue`, then you need some Converter anyway to set the actual value (`AllPeople[0].Address`). However I think the `FallbackValue` is what the OP need. In this case the Binding would fail and `FallbackValue` is used.

Comment: Thanks for the input. `TargetNullValue` doesn't work in this case; `FallbackValue` however does. Although it isn't exactly what I had asked, it at least saves me from writing a converter and solves the problem at hand in a standard way.